# Grab first cell of data in row by column

Tags: excel, vba

[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8F7F.png)

The image is for the excel data I am playing around with. I will attach my code later. But I am trying to fill Column H with the first found cell of each row from Column A-E. Ex. for row 1 it should find "B" and place that to H, row 2 should have "c" place that to "H", and so on row 3 "is" to H, row 4 "a" to H.

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. VBA has never been my strongest suit and I have been playing around with this for 2 days now. Here is my code.

```
Function findValue() As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim val As String

' Sets range of 5 columns to search in by column
Set rng = Range("A:E")                              

' searches through count of rows
For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row  
For Each cell In rng.Cells(i)
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
    MsgBox cell
    MsgBox i
    Else
        'MsgBox Range.(cell & i).Value
        findValue = cell
        Set rng = Range("A:E")
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
Next i
End Function
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be done with a formula, if you are interested.

Comment: Hopefully, you will accept Scott's offer of using a formula but, if not, is this meant to be a function or a subroutine?  i.e. are you trying to run the function to obtain a value (for one row?) or are you trying to run a subroutine to process all the rows at once?

Comment: need to obtain a value for each row. but I believe every call to =findValue() would equal the same thing correct? so a subroutine would be better then a function in this case.

Comment: If you want to use a formula, this would work perfectly `=INDEX(A1:E1,MATCH("*",A1:E1,0))` (unless you need to match numbers not strings)

Comment: So you are trying to use it as a UDF, with each call only processing a single row.

Comment: @YowE3K I would like to continue our discussion if possible.. so yes a UDF and each call processes/equals a single row yes.

Comment: @clickhere it also does not work if the values are inserted by formula with an empty string as one of the returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is intended as a UDF, I believe that the following code is what you are after:

```
Function findValue() As String
    Application.Volatile = True
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    r = Application.Caller.Row
    For c = 1 To 5
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(r, c)) Then
            findValue = Cells(r, c).Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    findValue = ""
End Function
```

---

An alternative method, where you pass the range to be checked rather than just checking the current row, would be:

```
Function findValue(rng As Range) As String
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            findValue = c.Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    findValue = ""
End Function
```

This could then be used in cell `H2` as `=findvalue(A2:E2)`, and has the advantage that it does not need to be marked `Volatile`.  ("Volatile" functions have to be recalculated every time anything at all changes on the worksheet.)

---

P.S.  I strongly suggest that you use an Excel formula instead (such as the one in [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42235222/6535336)) - why reinvent the wheel when Excel already provides the functionality?

Comment: Thank you @YowE3K this worked perfectly.. I need to get better at VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not by my PC so can't test it, but you could try this

```
Sub FindValue()
    Dim myRow As Range

    ' Sets Range of 5 columns to search in by column
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("A:E"),ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    ' searches through count of rows
    For each myRow in rng.Rows
        Cells(myRow.Row, "H").Value = myRow.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Cells(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula is:

```
=INDEX(A1:E1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A1:E1)/(A1:E1<>""),1))
```

[image]